# Fortran: matrix from symbolic functions

Tags: parsing, fortran, symbolic-math

I need to transform a set of symbolic equations defining relations between `\vec(a) = (a,b,c)` and `\vec(x) = (x,y)`, e.g.

```
a = 1./2 * x
b = -1./2 * x
c = 1./2 * y
```

into a matrix form so that I get the matrix A, when I write `\vec(a) = A * \vec(x)`:

```
/ a \   /  1./2   0   \    / x \
| b | = | -1./2   0   |  * \ y /
\ c /   \   0    1./2 /
```

Now the problem is, that the whole things needs to be in Fortran: reading the equations and transforming them to the matrix A.

I have found the module *fparser* (https://www.sourceforge.net/projects/fparser/) to evaluate symbolic math expressions, but I could need some help figuring out how to most efficiently build these matrices without doing too much string parsing...

Comment: Can you post what have you tried so far?

Comment: Not really, because I don't even know how to start. If I just take the expressions as strings, then I have to handle all possibly occurring parentheses, '/', '*', '+', '-' individually, that would be like writing an actual symbolic math parser .... 
Using an existing symbolic math library, I would need another library to build derivatives analytically. Then I could just say `A(1,1) = da/dx` and so on I guess...

Comment: It seems that you need both a text-to-expression parser and a CAS (computer algebra system) that can handle derivatives... if that's it, it's a waaay too broad question

Comment: Honestly, I thought someone can just hint me to a library that *can* do that, either both of it, or some advanced parsing.... Or am I the first person on earth to have such a problem? ;)

Comment: This is not the sort of thing that one would typically use Fortran for.  It would be significantly easier to use a CAS (i.e. sympy) to parse the expressions, compute derivatives and write the output to a .f90 file or some txt file that a fortran `read` statement can process.

Comment: *thought someone can just hint me to a library that can do that,* Library recommendations are off-topic at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's long ago, I want to post what helped me solving the issue:
I used `fparser` (http://fparser.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

An approach (workaround?) in 100% pure Fortran might be...

```
! calc.f90
program main
    implicit none
    real avec( 3 ), xvec( 2 ), A( 3, 2 )
    integer i

    do i = 1, size(xvec)
        xvec = 0 ; xvec(i) = 1.0
        call calc()
        A(:,i) = avec
    enddo

    do i = 1, size(avec)
        print *, A(i,:)
    enddo

contains
    subroutine calc()
        real a,b,c, x,y
        x = xvec(1)
        y = xvec(2)
        include 'eq.inc'
        avec = [a,b,c]
    end subroutine
end
```

eq.inc:

```
a = 1./2 * x
b = -1./2 * x
c = 1./2 * y
```

$ gfortran calc.f90 && ./a.out

```
  0.500000000       0.00000000    
 -0.500000000      -0.00000000    
   0.00000000      0.500000000
```

Comment: For nonlinear cases, maybe we can use finite difference or automatic differentiation (library?)